# Suitable Loss function for Order preserving Factoring of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, optimization, numerical-linear-algebra, factoring

(Old-Question)
Given a $n\times n$ symmetric matrix $X$, I would like to factor it using a vector $c$ of size $n \times 1$ such that: $\sum_{i,j} [X_{ij} \cdot c_i\cdot c_j]$  is minimum. How can I find the optimal vector $c^*$?

Constraint: The entries in the vector $c$ should sum to $1$.

Also, feel free to make notes about any optimality conditions/ assumptions that might go around this problem.

(New-Edited Question)

w.r.t the above question, this is an updated problem:
If for any 3 distinct indices i,j,k if the motive is to preserve the ordering between $X_{ij}$, $X_{jk}$ , $X_{ki}$ after the approximation with the vector c, defined in the old question above, what would be a suitable loss function containing X and c?

ex: If $X_{12}$ > $X_{23}$ < $X_{31}$ for a chosen i=1,j=2,k=3 then I would like to have $c_1.c_2$ > $c_2.c_3$ < $c_3.c_1$ after the approximation. What is a suitable loss function?

Comment: If you want to use TeX, write your TeX code within dollar signs. Please define your variables, what is $\sigma$? If this question is the same as your last question, please edit that question instead of starting a new question.

Comment: @ Calle I have not used a $\sigma$. This is a different question than the previous.

Comment: So you want the $c$ such that $c^T X c$ is minimized, subject to $e^Tc=1$ (where $e$ is a vector of all 1s)? Consider the method of Lagrange multipliers. Alternatively the solution is $c^* = (X^{-1}e) / (e^TX^{-1}e)$ assuming $X$ is invertible.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor Yes, that is the right formulation.

Comment: @ I have an updated question, that takes it from here. Do have a look.

Comment: Your new question is completely different from your old one.

Comment: @ Chris- I agree. Would you suggest that it be dealt with in a new posting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know how to solve this, consider looking at the [method of Lagrange multipliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).

The solution (assuming $X$ is invertible) is given by

$$c^* = (X^{-1}e) / (e^TX^{-1}e)$$

Note that this will only be a minimum if $X$ is [positive definite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix). If $X$ is negative definite then this is a maximum, and if $X$ is mixed then this will be a saddle.

I may expand this answer later - leave me a comment if that would be helpful.