# Is it possible to decompose a matrix as the product of two vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This question maybe stupid to some of you, but I would like to know whether it is possible to decompose a matrix $M_{m\times n}$ as the product of two vectors, i.e.

$$M_{m\times n} = \vec{y}_{m\times 1}\times\vec{x}_{1\times n}+const.$$

Obviously, this should be true for some cases, but I am not sure whether this conclusion is always hold. Meanwhile, I want to know at what condition, we can do this decomposition and how to find the vectors $\vec{y}$ and $\vec{x}$?

Comment: You should look into the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition), which is essentially a way to write a rank-$k$ matrix as a sum of $k$ such terms, $\mathbf M=\sum\limits_{i=1}^k\sigma_i\mathbf u_i\mathbf v_i^T$. In particular, you can write $\mathbf M$ as a *single* term $\sigma\mathbf u\mathbf v^T$ if and only if $\mathbf M$ is rank $1$. (If you don't like the presence of the extra scalar $\sigma$, you can think of $\sigma\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$, or $\mathbf u$ and $\sigma\mathbf v$, as your two vectors.)

Comment: Much better than either of the proposed answers, IMO.

Comment: @RahulNarain: Well, or rank zero. :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Factorize a Symmetric matrix as an 'Approximation' with an outer product.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102316/factorize-a-symmetric-matrix-as-an-approximation-with-an-outer-product)

Comment: @TimSeguine That question is specific to symmetric matrices, and the answer there uses that assumption. Here we have a rectangular matrix.

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY I get the impression from the comment from the OP to the top answer here, that they are interested precisely in symmetric matrices. If that is not the case, then you are quite correct.

Answer (score 7):

If you by $\times$ mean the cross product, then this of course doesn't make sense.

If you mean a matrix product, then this also will not work. Take for example 
$$
\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}
$$
and assume that
$$
\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1} = \pmatrix{a \\ b}\pmatrix{c & d} = \pmatrix{ac & da \\ bc & bd}.
$$
You see that $ac \neq 0$ and that $bd \neq 0$, so $a, b, c, d\neq 0$. So $da\neq 0$ and $bc\neq 0$.
(I assume that your constant is zero, otherwise you would just take that constant to be $M$ and $x$ and $y$ both zero vectors.)

Answer (score 7):

In general, rank $n$ matrix can be expressed as  sum of $n$ rank 1 matrix using singular value decomposition.

When the matrix is rank 1 we can express as you suggested in your question.
If it is $>1$, we can't express like that.

Answer (score 6):

No, simply because the space of matrices is $mn$-dimensional, and the space of pairs of vectors is $(m+n)$-dimensional, which can be much smaller. The best thing one can do is decompose into a sum of $\min(m,n)$ products, and this decomposition is of course not even close to being unique.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What if we have $M_{m,m}$ is a symmetric matrix, which I believe we can write it as $$$$

Answer (score 1):

Let us think of this as trying to solve for two vectors $a_{m \times 1},b_{n \times 1}$ given a matrix $A_{m\times n}$ such that $ab^T = A$

Note that the number of variables you have are number of elements in $a$ + number of elements in $b$

$ab^{T}$ gives you a matrix $B_{m \times n}$ with $m\times n$ elements.

$A = B$ if every element of $A$ = every element of $B$.

This means that you need to satisfy $m \times n$ equation with $m+n$ variables.
This system doesn't necessarily have a solution unless there are constraints on the elements of $A$ itself.

In general $m \times n \neq (m+n)$

Even when $m+n = mn$ it is not guaranteed that this problem can be solved.
consider $A$ to be $2 \times 2 $. You run into issues when one of the entries is zero as shown in one of the above answers.

This was just to give an intuitive picture as to why you can't always express a matrix as a product of two 1-dimensional matrices.